# git: Check if filter-branch would touch already pushed commits

Tags: git, push, git-filter-branch

Basically i want to get a warning, if a filter-branch would change a commit which is already pushed.

Suppose i want to do a

```
git filter-branch ... --ancestry-path A^..HEAD
```

Of course i could create a list of affected Hashes and "comm"pare this with a list of all hashes already pushed. Is there are more straightforward solution?

EDIT: I am interested in a scriptable solution.

Comment: I wonder if it's easier to ask forgiveness than ask permission: just make the change and try a `git push`, and if it fails, revert the `filter-branch` change.

Comment: Isn't it enough to check only immediate `A^` children? (It should be `A` if I understand your case correctly). If they are not pushed, then none of commits on top of them are not pushed as well

Comment: @max630: But how to prove that they haven't been pushed so far? (regarding the currently registered remotes)

Comment: something like `git branch --remotes --contains A`

Comment: @max630: Yes, this is a solution, but i still need to do some ugly post processing. It seems to be a matter of taste... `git log --oneline $COMMIT..$(git branch  -r --contains $COMMIT | { grep -v -- " -> " || echo $COMMIT; } | tail -1 | tr -d ' ') | grep "." && { echo 'Some already pushed commits are affected!'; exit 1; }`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're ahead of `master` (or whatever branch you're working on) and you run `git status`, you'll see something like this:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
```

The easiest thing to do is just run your `filter-branch` and then run `status` again. If none of the changes affect commits that were already pushed, the message won't change. If you did change something that was pushed, the message will become something like:

```
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
```

If you want to bail out, save the commit SHA from before you run `filter-branch` and you can get back to it with `git reset --hard SHA`.

Answer (score 0):

I should have emphazised that i was looking for a scriptable solution. My current solution is quite heavy and might not work in all situations:

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMIT="$1"

git log --format="%H %h %s" --ancestry-path $COMMIT"^.." | \
grep -f \
  <(comm -12 \
    <(git log --format=%H --ancestry-path $COMMIT"^.." | sort) \
    <(git log --format=%H $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/remotes/) | sort)\
  ) | \
cut -d " " -f 2- | grep "." && { echo 'Some already pushed commits are affected!'; exit 1; }

git filter-branch ... --ancestry-path $COMMIT"^.."
```